# How to get a POD section into a string?

Tags: perl

How to get a POD section into a variable:

```
pod2usage(-verbose => 99, -sections => "DESCRIPTION"); # Goes on STDOUT

=head1 DESCRIPTION

    A description

=cut
```

I just want to assign `DESCRIPTION` to a variable instead displaying it on `STDOUT`.

I am currently investigating this way. It is complicated and it doesn't work:

```
sub pod2scalar {
    use File::Temp 'tempfile';
    my ($fh, $filename) = tempfile(UNLINK => 1);
    open OLDOUT, '>&STDOUT';
    {
        local *STDOUT;
        open STDOUT, ">", $filename or warn "Can't open $filename: $!";

        #pod2usage(@_); # Doesn't work... I don't know why...
        print STDOUT "This is captured in \$str";

        close STDOUT;
    }
    open STDOUT, '>&OLDOUT' or die "Can't restore stdout: $!";
    close OLDOUT or die "Can't close OLDOUT: $!";
    open $fh, "<", $filename or warn "Can't open $filename: $!";
    my $str = do { local $/, <$fh> };
    close $fh;
    $str;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can open a scalar variable for output by passing a reference to `open` in place of a file name

Then you can provide the file handle as the value of the `-output` option of `pod2usage` to get the data sent to your scalar variable

You will also want to set an `-exitval` of `'NOEXIT'` so that you get a chance to use what you have captured

It would look like this

```
use Pod::Usage 'pod2usage';

sub pod2scalar {
  open my $fh, '>', \my $text;
  pod2usage(@_, -output => $fh, -exitval => 'NOEXIT');
  $text;
}
```

Comment: @bessarabov: Why is that? I've removed it anyway as it's more concise if I just add the new parameters in the procedure call, but there's no way it can do any harm to manipulate `@_`. After all it is very common practice to extract parameters from the array by using `shift`, so if you can *remove* elements from `@_` there shouldn't be a problem with *adding* to it!

Comment: Hm... I never used @_ as a normal array, I only used it as a thing to access parameters passed to sub. Now I've tried to construct some example that breaks because of direct usage of @_, but I couldn't do it. Maybe it is ok to use it, but I have never seen such usage before.

Comment: @bessarabov: `@_` just happens to be where Perl puts parameter values when a subroutine is called. Otherwise it's a very ordinary array

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent perl library [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny) that simplifies saving stdout/stderr.

By default `pod2usage` exits the program, so you must specify `-exitval => "noexit"`.

Here is a full working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Pod::Usage;
use Capture::Tiny ':all';

=head1 DESCRIPTION

A description

=cut

my $stdout = capture_merged {
    pod2usage(-verbose => 99, -sections => "DESCRIPTION", -exitval => "noexit");
};

say "## Captured";
say $stdout;

__END__

This will output:

## Captured
Description:
    A description
```